# Debug assertion failed every time i click a button?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, dialog

I am working on an MFC application which has various buttons.  I recently added a new dialog which opens when you click one of the buttons.

But for some reason, now every time I click ANY of my buttons, I get the following message:

[pic of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hQzw.png)

I have spent hours trying to figure out what I could have done wrong.  I would post some code, but I have over 3000 lines thus far and I have no idea what I would even show.

Anyone have any clue what could be causing this?

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8.1

Comment: click retry on that dialog, whatever code segment it breaks into is much more useful for debugging it

Comment: Use the debugger. It can tell you where the program stopped, and why, and how it got there. Most of this information comes from the debugger stack window, and clicking on the levels in it to go to the relevant code.

Comment: It's **really** time you learn how to use a debugger, it'a a **huge** time saver. The basics of the Visual Studio debugger are extreamly simple.

Comment: If it's asserting in afxwin2.inl it's typically because the window handle attached to the CWnd is not valid.